# what is the use of record type in salesforce

Tags: record-type

What is the use of record type?Can you explain in brief.
Can't we just use page layouts to restrict the fields instead of record types.

Answer (score 2):

Record types allow you to offer different business processes, picklist values, and page layouts to different users. Record types can be used in various ways, for example:

If you have 2 types of cases in your Organization.

1. Product Issues
2. Product Ideas.

There are two options for you.

1. You can create picklist on Case object and put both values into that picklist and while creating a new records you can select corresponding value while saving the record.

But in broader view it is better to have a separate layout, picklist values etc. for both types of cases. Record type comes into the picture in this situation.

You can create two different page layout for both case type and while creating a new record system will ask you what type of record you want to create and in that way you can bifurcate records.

Record type will also help you to define different picklist values for single picklist field.

So for example if you have a picklist field Status__c it can show

Open
Close
Resolved

when you are on Product issue record creation screen but if you are on Product Ideas record creation screen same picklist field can show you

Open
Added into future road map
Delivered